# Not getting actual requested URL on server side in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a middleware for auth.

Basically the middleware handles the authentication.

`ctx.pathname` returning the **wrong** value. For example, if I request `http://localhost:4001/student/courses/bd478029-2493-4602-9047-ab4ed83f4538` this **url** on the **browser** then it's returning `/login` instead `/student/courses/[id]`. But, for `http://localhost:4001/login` its returning as the value as expected i.e: `/login`

What's going on?

---

Here is my `authMiddleware.js` code

```
import { studentHome, studentLogin, teacherHome, teacherLogin } from "../utils/staticFields";
import redirectTo from "./redirectTo"
import UserManager from "./UserManager";

const authMiddleware = ctx => {
    try {
        console.log('@@@@@', ctx.pathname, Date.now())
        const user = UserManager.getCookie('user',ctx)
        const userObj = user ? JSON.parse(user) : null;
        let redirectUrl = ""
        // const prevUrl = ctx.asPath
        if(userObj){
            if(userObj.type === "teacher" && (!ctx.pathname.startsWith("/teacher") || ctx.pathname === "/teacher/login")) redirectUrl = teacherHome;  // user is logged in, redirect to teacher portal
            else if(userObj.type === "student" && !ctx.pathname.startsWith("/student")) redirectUrl = studentHome;   // user is logged in, redirect to student portal
        } else if(!userObj && ctx.pathname.startsWith("/teacher") && ctx.pathname !== "/teacher/login"){
            redirectUrl = teacherLogin;          // user is not logged in, redirect to login (teacher)
        } else if(!userObj && ctx.pathname.startsWith("/student")){
            // UserManager.setIntendedUrl(ctx,prevUrl)
            redirectUrl = studentLogin;          // user is not logged in, redirect to login (student)
        }

        if(redirectUrl){
            console.log("REDIRECTING FROM", ctx.pathname, "TO", redirectUrl)
            redirectTo(redirectUrl, { res: ctx.res, status: 301 });
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error in authMiddleware", error)
    }
}

export default authMiddleware
```

`_app.js`

```
...

MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ Component, ctx }) => {
    const pageProps = Component.getInitialProps ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx) : {};

    authMiddleware(ctx);

    return { pageProps }
}
```

Comment: The middleware redirects to `studentLogin` if the `user` cookie is not set. Maybe you'e only seeing what gets logged after the redirect happens?

Comment: On the fly `console.log('@@@@@', ctx.pathname, Date.now())` this should print the req url but it's always `/login` when session is not there.